# Obtaining a Gravatar API key

Tags: api-key, gravatar

Does anyone know how to obtain a Gravatar API key? I've seen countless examples and tutorials for Gravatar that mention simply using your key, but I haven't been able to find out how to get one. As far as I can tell, there doesn't seem to be a way to do so on their site directly. Is this something they still offer/use?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

To obtain your profile image you just need to md5 your email address and make a request like this `<img src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/md5(email)" />`

Comment: And that makes sense. I believe I was trying to use the gravatar API to progromatically update a user's gravatar image.

Comment: I don't think you can do this - though it would be nice if you could.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you've moved on since you posted this nearly 10 years ago.. But after several hours in the same rabbit hole, I think I finally found a what we were looking for

https://apikey.wordpress.com/